# Convergence of probabilities imply convergence of joint probability

Tags: pr.probability, limits-and-convergence

**Context:** Suppose I have two pairs of sequences of random variables $X_n, \tilde{X}_n$ and $Y_n, \tilde{Y}_n$, where $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are not necessarily independent for any $n$, but $\tilde{X}_n$ and $\tilde{Y}_n$ are independent for any $n$.

Moreover I know that dependence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ is getting weaker when $n \to \infty$ in the following sense:

$$ \text{sup}_{A, B} |P(\{X_n \in A\} \& \{Y_n \in B\}) - P(X_n \in A) P(Y_n \in B)| \to 0, n \to \infty. $$

**Question:**
I have the following convergences for two sets $A$ and $B$:

1. $|P(X_n \in A) - P(\tilde{X_n} \in A)| \to 0, n \to \infty$;
2. $|P(Y_n \in B) - P(\tilde{Y_n} \in B)| \to 0, n \to \infty$;

Do this convergences imply the following convergence?

$$ |P \left( \{ X_n \in A \} \& \{Y_n \in B \} \right) - P \left( \{ \tilde{X}_n \in A \} \& \{\tilde{Y}_n \in B \} \right)| \to 0 $$

I was trying to find any method on how to prove it... Any support will be very appreciated.

Comment: It all depends on how $X_n$ and $Y_n$ depend on each other...

Comment: @tsnao, thank you for the comment, I corrected the question, there was a typo: $X_n$ and $Y_n$ could be dependent, but $\tilde{X}_n$ and $\tilde{Y}_n$ are independent for any $n$.

Comment: This is hopeless without information on the joint distribution of $X_n,Y_n$. For example, suppose that $P(X_n=1)=P(X_n=0)=1/2$, $Y_n=X_n$, and the tilde variables are independent with the same distribution. Then $P(X_n=Y_n=1)=1/2$ while $P(\tilde{X_n}=\tilde{Y_n}=1)=1/4$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling, but in this case there won't be convergence of $|P(X_n \in A) - P(\tilde{X}_n \in A)| \to 0$.

Comment: @Grigori: The difference is zero identically, $X_n$, $\tilde{X_n}$ have the same distribution. (There is no $n$ dependence in my example, I'm just writing this to be in line with your notation.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling, thank you, I misunderstood you. I know something about the dependence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$, I will add it to the question.

Comment: It's just that (1) and (2) make sense even if $X$s and $Y$s are defined on different probability spaces. Last formula requires them to be defined on the same probability space. And there is infinite number of ways of coupling two laws.

Comment: @tsnao, fair point. I assume now that these RV are defined on the same space. I also added the "dependence vanishing condition". Would it help somehow?

Comment: Now this is a simple fact about sequences of numbers.

Comment: Indeed, @IosifPinelis, thank you for saying that :) I think simple triangle inequality will solve everything here.